# Integrating Spring MVC Spring Security with Undertow web container

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, wildfly-8, undertow

With Undertow breaking scalability records in some of the benchmarks very little information is available to how to migrate Spring MVC +Spring Security project to this new container from Tomcat.

Can anybody provide some pointer as to how to proceed with it?

Undertow claims to implemet Servlet 3.1 specs & is a container for the same.

I've embedded Spring in Jetty before,is the process same or it seems its not possible as of now?

Comment: A Spring Web Application is just a web application that requires a Servlet Container, therefore it (should) work on Jetty, Tomcat or other Servlet contains. For the most Servlet Container the deployment process works the same way: put the WAR in an special directory or use some GUI or API.

Comment: Even i'm assuming the same, but undertow is very different from existing containers its more like node.js. Another way to find it out is by taking some timeout & do a PoC. I posted here to find out if somebody has already done that. :)

Comment: After all these years of experience, would you recommend using Spring + Undertow? I'm looking into it right now.

Comment: go for it it works just fine!

Answer (score 6):

So i got down to get the PoC up & running ,checkout https://github.com/rohitdev/project-templates

https://blog.groovymaven.page/posts/deploy-spring-in-undertow

Comment: Thanks for the example, but is the code in Github complete?, it does not load from Net Beans.